# Как организовать класс с настройками программы?

Tags: c#, архитектура

Доброго времени суток. Интересует вопрос грамотного проектирования класса с настройками. Где их лучше хранить, как считывать с диска и прочие нюансы.
В своем случае я сделал статический класс с статическими полями доступными только на чтение, что бы можно было не создавая объект этого класса использовать его в любой части приложения.
Инициализирую я его классом, который находится внутри, но это по-моему несколько избыточно.

```
    public static class Setting
{
    public static string HomePath { get; private set; }
    public static bool IsInitSetting { get; private set; }

    private class _Setting : IDisposable
    {
        public string HomePath;


        public _Setting() { }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            HomePath = null;

        }
    }

    public static void Init()
    {
        if (!IsInitSetting)
        {
            using (_Setting setting = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("settings.json")).ToObject<_Setting>())
            {
                HomePath = setting.HomePath;
                IsInitSetting = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы уберёте статик из объявления класса Setting и сделаете его синглтоном, то сможете сериализовать/десереализовать непосредственно экземпляр Setting.

Comment: Соответственно, инициализация будет в конструкторе синглтона, и вам не придётся самостоятельно делать Init()

Comment: А в тему >>грамотного проектирования<<, рекомендуется вообще разделить Settings и SettingsLoader на отдельные классы.

Comment: А чем вас не устроил `App.config`? `HomePath` - различного рода пути получают во время выполнения с помощью `Evironment.CurrentDirectory`, `Environment.GetFolderPath()` и т.п., а не записывают в конфиги. И если вы делаете отдельный статич.класс для хранения/извлечения настроек, то вполне достаточно в этом классе иметь статический конструктор, а не усложнять на пустом месте с внутренним классом и проч.

Comment: А почему не использовать готовые майкрософтовские Settings? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings Там всё уже продумано за вас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Статический класс плох тем, что он привносит неявную зависимость. Если позже вы захотите часть своей программы перенести в другой проект, это будет сделать сложно, потому что вам придётся переносить и класс `Settings`, который, кстати, обладает двумя ответственностями в нарушения принципа единственной ответственности. Он а) умеет загружать настройки и б) предоставляет к ним доступ.

В другом проекте настройки могут храниться по другому, не в JSON-файле, так что перенос одного класса может вылиться в большой рефакторинг.

Чтобы избавиться от лишних зависимостей их надо инвертировать, в соответствии с принципом *инверсии зависимостей*. Класс, который использует настройки не зависит от класса настроек, вместо этого он говорит, что ему для работы потребуются вот такие параметры.

В качестве примера давайте рассмотрим кусок движка блогов, а конкретно метод, постранично возвращающий комментарии к посту:

```
public class CommentRepository
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Comment> ReadAllCommentsByPostId(int postId, int page = 1)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DbContext(Settings.ConnectionString))
        {
            int offset = Settings.PageSize * (page - 1);
            int count = Settings.PageSize;

            return dbContext.Comments
                            .Where(x => x.PostId = PostId)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
                            .Skip(offset)
                            .Take(count)
                            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

В этом метод мы обращаемся к настройкам `Settings.ConnectionString` и `Settings.PageSize`. Эта зависимость неявная, поскольку нигде в интерфейсе класса мы не видим, что методы или конструкторы зависят от `Settings`.

Сделаем эту зависимость явной:

```
public class CommentRepository
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    private readonly int pageSize;

    public CommentRepository(string connectionString, int pageSize)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Comment> ReadAllCommentsByPostId(int postId, int page = 1)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            int offset = pageSize * (page - 1);
            int count = pageSize;

            return dbContext.Comments
                            .Where(x => x.PostId = PostId)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
                            .Skip(offset)
                            .Take(count)
                            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы работать с *инверсией зависимостей* полезно использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку. Их для C# существует не меньше десятка. Вот, как мы можем зарегистрировать класс `CommentRepository` в контейнере:

```
var jsonSettings = File.ReadAllText("settings.json");
var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(jsonSettings);

builder.Register<CommentRepository>()
       .As<ICommentRepository>()
       .WithParameter("connectionString", settings.ConnectionString)
       .WithParameter("pageSize", settings.PageSize);
```

Чем этот подход отличается от предыдущего? Тем, что если нам потребуется класс `CommentRepository` вынести в другой проект, это будет проще сделать. На самом деле он зависит от классов `DbContext` и `Comment`, но в данном случае это нормально: мы не может перенести репозиторий комментариев без самих комментариев.

Но мы убрали зависимость от класса `Settings`. Теперь и класс `Settings` стал проще, это обычный DTO, не статический класс, не синглтон. Он просто описывает структуру файла настроек. Загрузка настроек вынесена туда, где классы регистрируются в контейнере Autofac.

В другом проекте мы можем использовать другой контейнер, например, NInject, и настройки будем загружать не из JSON, а из переменных окружения, и при этом нам не придётся вносить ни одного изменения в `CommentRepository`, `Comment` и `DbContext`.

За это придётся расплачиваться изменением архитектуры программы и применением того самого *внедрения зависимостей*. О нём [очень хорошую книгу написал Марк Симан](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/35161137/).

Comment: Плюсую, но есть вопросы. Что делать, если настройки надо использовать в наборе разных, не связанных между собой модулях одного солюшена? Как организовать не только чтение, но и запись настроек и их сохранение? Вы писали про нарушение SRP, но разве чтение настроек/десериализация их в класс и сборка DI контейнера не разные ответственности?

Comment: Далее, вы показываете загрузку настроек из json файла. Это, в принципе, хороший подход, но настройки имеют обыкновение изменяться, обрастать новыми полями или изменять тип настроек. Настройки также могут быть обязательными или иметь значение по умолчанию. Какие бы механизмы для работы с этим вы предложили?

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос появится, когда в настройках надо будет хранить не простые типы данных, а что то сложнее, например, конфигурацию представления грида с колонками, сортировкой и прочим. Должен ли класс Settings знать о том, какие именно типы данных он хранит, и как это поддерживать, если у вас 200 модулей со своими уникальными настройками? Не сильно ли распухнет от такого Settings класс?

Comment: @tym32167 на эти вопросы ответы будут слишком большими для комментариев. Я посовещался с модераторами и они рекомендуют задать вопросы отдельно, чтобы на них можно было дать развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Я извиняюсь заранее, я не хочу холиварить или спорить, но верно ли я понял: вы говорите, что не будете отвечать тут ни на один из моих вопросов потому что каждый из них (включая вопросы, которые касаются непосредственно вашего ответа) требуют слишком большого ответа? Я то задал эти вопросы, так как ваш ответ мне показался не полным, и было бы здорово хотя бы упоминуть о тех вещах, что я спросил, в вашем ответе.

Comment: @tym32167 Я понял вашу позицию, но модераторы были единодушны.

Comment: Я уже пообщался в том вашем вопросе на мете, меня просто не так поняли - мне нужно было сразу отметить намерения улучшить ответ, чтобы не было недопонимания. В любом случае, если вы считаете, что темы, что я затронул, не должны быть в вашем ответе - то ок, я не настаиваю, просто предположил, что это может быть полезным.